# Simplest way to validate a text file

Tags: c#, api

I am new to Visual Studio Code and API. I can't really find any relevant answers to what i want (may be because i don't really know the exact terms to what to search since it's all new to me).
I need to create an API to validate a text file. I'll be given a file path, i need to fetch the file from the given path, read each line and check for the validation.
Validations are as follows :

1. Check for the number of columns
2. Check for the particular columns that should be there in the file otherwise throw an exception.
3. Check the Datatype of each column
4. Validation of PAN, Mobile No. etc.

The first line is the header line. the file is ~ separated

What i have been told by my manager.
To create a two separate class file for header and details with data annotation.

I have no idea what does it even means. Please if anyone can help me this.

Comment: Note that this is a Q&A site and not a code writing service. See also how to [ask]

Comment: This seems to be some kind of "CSV" file with the tilde character as delimiter? You could split each line into individual items then check on these. Or, maybe use a library like CSVHelper. Does this make sense?

Comment: @KlausGütter : Yeah i understand that brother. I just need a push to how to start with it, later i am sure i can manage with it.

Comment: Wow. Micro- _and_ Undermanagement at the same time ... My advice to you: Divide and Conquer. You have an exhausting list of things that are required. Try to identify borders so you can separate different parts that can be done separately, than do each separately. For example: Fetching a text file from some path doesn't sound too hard and is separate from what is to be done _with_ that file afterwards ...

Comment: BTW: Requirements lack on instructions what to do with validation results...

Comment: @Marcel : Yeah it's a "CSV" file with tilde character. Do you have any idea on how to create a class file with data annotation?

Comment: Do you know what "Data Annotation" _is_? Maybe you should investigate that first, so you know what your manager is expecting from you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Why have you told your manager that you can write computer programs?

Comment: @Toto I guess they talk about this: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/attributes This way of annotating properties is very common in C#. Please read up as Fildor suggested. It's a powerful concept and you will benefit from knowledge about it also in other areas.

Comment: @Fildor : Thanks bro. i have just started with coding.

Comment: @rioV8 Not every user of SO is a software developer. Every single one of us once had that mountain of requirements in front of us that made us freeze and not even know where to start. Let's not be so judgemental, that's all I am saying. Nobody benefits from "noob-shaming" OP.

Comment: @Toto _"I need to create an API to validate a text file"_ - Also, please specify what _kind_ of API is expected of you? An API can be many very different things. From a simple console program, a library, up to hosted REST API (just to name a few examples). The inner workings of would be similar, but the approaches / project setup would vary quite significantly.

Comment: @Fidor I'm not noob-shaming. If he is starting coding he should read a book or some training site and practice simple stuff first and start to know the possibilities of the C# library. Yes learning to program takes a lot of time and practice. Start simple.

Answer (score 1):

Since this some form of "CSV" file (with the tilde character being the separator), I suggest using one of the existing libraries to do the task instead of writing code yourself. I like the [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) library, but surely there are others.

Read about annotations from their examples: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/attributes

The concept basically is to **write a class with properties that match the columns of your data**. Then annotate each property with clues for the library to automagically map the properties to the columns with proper data conversion as needed.

Such data conversions are very common also for other input and output operations in general.